# Can't connect to RethinkDB locally. Getting "rdp protocol port (bad magic number)"

Tags: javascript, database, database-connection, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python

I am trying to connect to RethinkDB locally and I am getting a strange error message that I cannot find any other documentation on.

The connection works on my office computer but does not work on my MacBook Pro 10.9.2 at home.

When I run my application I get this error:

```
{ name: 'RqlDriverError',
  msg: 'Server dropped connection with message: "ERROR: this is the rdb protocol port (bad magic number)"',
  message: 'Server dropped connection with message: "ERROR: this is the rdb protocol port (bad magic number)"' }
```

I am requiring RethinkDB in the top of the file. This is the code in my app that won't connect:

```
r.connect({ 
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 28015 
},
function(err, conn) { 
    if (err){
        return console.error(err);
    };
    r.db('Tictactoe').table('Users').insert({
        move: req.query.move
    }).run(conn, function(err, res){
        if (err){
            return console.error(err);
        }
    });

});
```

Here is a link to my Github repo. https://github.com/RaySinlao/tic_tac_toe/blob/master/app.js

I just think it is very odd that it works on my company computer but not my home computer after I set everything up exactly the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run

```
npm uninstall rethinkdb
```

And then

```
npm install rethinkdb@1.12.0-1
```

That should fix your problem (you need the server and the driver to have the same major versions - the first two numbers).

If at some point you update the server, don't forget to update the driver with

```
npm install rethinkdb
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your RethinkDB JavaScript driver is up to-date, and that the server and client driver version match (check `rethinkdb --version` and `npm list` for the `rethinkdb` package.)

The error message `"ERROR: this is the rdb protocol port (bad magic number)"` is being improved for clarity to indicate a version mismatch, see this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/2302

Comment: When I run:
    rethinkdb --version

I get:
    rethinkdb 1.12.3 (CLANG 5.1 (clang-503.0.40))

and when I run:
    npm list

I get:
    rethinkdb@1.13.0-2
    ---- bluebird@2.2.1

Different versions. Is this causing the crash?

Comment: Yes, the latest version of RethinkDB is v1.13, so until you upgrade your server, you can just use the v1.12 version of the driver (as per neumino's instructions.)